# How can I share a url containing a hash # in linkedin?

Tags: javascript, url, linkedin-api, share, hashbang

I need to share with linkedin a url containing a hash `#` like this `https://example.com/#/item/49`

I have already tried using # and %23 instead of hash.

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://example.com/#/item/49">share</a>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://example.com/%23/item/49">share</a>
```

not working

Comment: Hash is ignored by the server, but you can use some minifier (url shortener) and will include it for you, just search minifier that will redirect to page with hash.

Comment: Where is the JavaScript in this?

Comment: I think that some shorteners have even APIs and you will be able to write code that will share url and shorten it before creating a link. If you're creating the links dynamically.

Comment: try this too `https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsquarefoot.lk%2F%23%2Fitem%2F49`

Comment: The other solution is to remove the hash and use History API.

Comment: @jcubic how would that api be useful?

Comment: @mplungjan I assume he have single page application if he remove `#` and use history api for routes, he will be able to have URLs like `https://squarefoot.lk/item/49`. Unless the url is not he's app in that case he can't use it.

Comment: @mplungjan i used JavaScript for generating this url.

Comment: Related: http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs